# How to combine scale style and hover event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a container with images and scrollbar. My task is to scale image when hover event occurs. The snippet below demonstrates that.

The problem is cropping image on hover. If I remove the `overflow` style, the crop is gone, but the container also lost the scrollbar.

How can I display a scaled image when hovering over the image without cropping and at the same time save scrollbar for the container?

```css
img {
  width: 28px
}

button:hover img {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #3c3f43;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: scale(4.0)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; width: 200px; height: 50px">
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `button:hover img {position: absolute;}`  How about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the image and set it `position: fixed;`. In the example below I use jquery:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'button', function(){
  const t = $(this);
  const cloneImg = t.find('img').clone();
  cloneImg.addClass('clone-img');
  cloneImg.css({
    left: t.offset().left,
    top: t.offset().top,
  })
  t.append(cloneImg);
})

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'button', function(){
  $(this).find('.clone-img').remove();
})
```

```css
img {
  width: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.clone-img {
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}

button:hover .clone-img{
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div style="width: 300px; height: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="overflow: auto; width: 200px; height: 50px">
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
    <button><img src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/6468f883aee1f7f4756770b5/3x"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```